# Can I overlay a CartoDB visualisation on Bing Maps base?

Tags: carto, layers, overlay, visualisation, bing-maps

If I am using Bing Maps as my base map, can i overlay a CartoDB visualisation (that I created earlier) on top of it? If so how do I go about doing that? The example on the cartodb site only refers to LeafLet Maps but when I try "cartodb.createLayer" with Bing Maps as my base map, it throws an error:

> "Cartodb.js can't guess the map type"

Not sure what I am missing. I am using the Bing Maps' JavaScript library and wondering if CartoDB even supports Bing Maps.

Comment: check out: https://gist.github.com/javisantana/c20601e782aca32fc863

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but requires development. If using the Bing Maps V8 control a custom overlay can be created to build a CartoDB layer. I haven't seen any one do this yet, but have looked into it and it doesn't look overly difficult to do.